# Using alias in Laravel Query

Tags: join, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a function on a model:

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $allusers = DB::table('users')->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')->get();
        return $allusers;
    }
```

This works fine except the id of the user is replaced by the id of the country:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#201 (20) { ["id"]=> int(42) ["name"]=> string(11) "Jim Elliott" ... and so on
```

The ID should be 1 as the country_id is 42.

Should I add an alias for the country ID and is so how? Or can I restrict the fields of the countries table to just be the country and flag?

Comment: have you tried
`$allusers = DB::table('users')->join('countries', 'users.country_id', '=', 'countries.id')->get();`

Comment: Sorry it made no difference

Comment: Proper define your relations and then just use `return User::with('country');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = DB::table('users')->join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'users.country_id')
    ->select(DB::raw(
      "SELECT users.*,countries.*, users.id AS 'user_id',
      countries.id AS 'country_id'"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I cheated with a view in which I linked the 2 tables and gave an alias to the country ID. Not an elegant solution but it has worked. I am sure there is a proper way to do it in Laravel without a view, so my function then became:

```
$allusers = DB::table('v_users')->get();
return $allusers;
```